# Uploaded Excel Blob not getting created properly

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

The Excel file that I'm trying to upload to blob is not getting created properly although it is getting uploaded successfully. I'm using the `UploadBlobAsync` for the same.

```
private async Task UploadExcelToBlobAsync(string fileName, MemoryStream excelContentMemoryStream)
        {
            try
            {
                string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
                string fileExtension = ".xslx";
                fileName = $"{fileName}_{currentDateTime}{fileExtension}";
                var blobContainerClient = _blobService.GetBlobContainerClient(); // this is properly instatiated
                await blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, excelContentMemoryStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Strangely though, the same `MemoryStream` object I'm using further in my code to perform some logic. So I guess, the issue is not with the `MemoryStream` object also. Below is a snip of the generated Excel, the generated file size is 14KB while the one that I had uploaded was of 20KB:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm possibly doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance.

*Addition:* Below is the code which calls the method `UploadExcelToBlobAsync`:

```
public async Task<(string, List<CustomObject>?)> UploadExcelAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(ms);
                    DataSet excelDataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet();

                    await UploadExcelToBlobAsync(file.FileName, ms);

                    var resp = await ValidateAndInsertExcelData(excelDataSet);

                    return resp;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the size of the uploaded blob?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri apologies, the file is not exactly saying corrupted but it is not getting generated properly either. I have edited my post and added all relevant details there. Kindly check.

Comment: Looks like an issue with how you are reading the content into the memory stream. Can you share the code for that as well? Thanks.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri added now..

Comment: You might try ms.Position = 0; before await UploadExcelToBlobAsync(file.FileName, ms);

Comment: the screenshot you show looks like what you'd get if you opened an excel file in notepad and then saved it.  When this file is output make sure mime-type is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code, if the downloaded file does not appear that prompt, my suggestion is to use my sample code.

[image]

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadExcel")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadExcelAsync([FromForm] IFormCollection formfile)
    {
        string sasuri = "https://br***nWTT5GnC1LpHsD7p5Fo2lHpFM1nafAHjL9Fozf%2FvDdg%3D";
        Uri container_uri = new Uri(sasuri);
        var container_client = new BlobContainerClient(container_uri);

        var file = formfile.Files.FirstOrDefault();

        string fileName = file.FileName;
        BlobClient blobClient = container_client.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        
        Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var result = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
        stream.Close();
        return Ok(result.GetRawResponse().Status);
    }
```

If you use my sample code, there is still such a prompt:

```
The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it.
```

Then please try to use another computer as client for test. If the issue still exists. It means the Microsoft office version or scurity has some problem. [Then try this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-6-2022-update-for-excel-2013-kb5002268-1af9090f-2af9-4839-800e-215d5ee72a6d).